# Python Function in Spark

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to round the  deadline_date column forward or backwards based on a flag on the  activity_prioritization_rounding dataframe. -1 means backwards, 0 means nothing and 1 means forward.

The function works when I use a single date as a variable, but I struggling to apply it on an entire dataset. The error I am getting is "ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions." when trying to pass the column part of the function. Relatively new building function in python.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import next_day, date_sub
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date


def next_date(column,date,dayOfWEek):
  if column == -1:
    return date_sub(next_day(date,dayOfWEek),0)
  elif column == 1:
    return date_sub(next_day(date,dayOfWEek),7)
  else:
    return date


activity_prioritization_rounding= sql("""select * from spa.activity_master""")
activity_prioritization_rounding.withColumn(
   "New_Date",
    next_date(col("deadline_rounding"),col("deadline_date"),"Friday"))
)
```

Comment: Can you post the trace? Have a feeling your error is deeper than the code provided.

Comment: just converting `if-elif-else` in the function *next_date()* to use `when().when().otherwise()`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a `udf` out of your python function and send `Friday` as a column, since it won't get broadcasted across the dataframe. You can do so using `lit`.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, next_day, date_sub, to_date, lit
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType

activity_prioritization_rounding.withColumn("New_Date",udf(next_date(col("deadline_rounding"),col("deadline_date"),lit("Friday"), DateType())))
```

EDIT:
As @jxc rightly mentioned, you cannot use spark functions inside `UDF`.

Simplying this to `when().when().otherwise()`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, next_day, date_sub, to_date, lit, when, col

day_of_week = "Friday"
activity_prioritization_rounding.withColumn("New_Date", when(
    col("deadline_rounding") == -1, date_sub(next_day(col("deadline_date"), day_of_week), 0)).when(
    col("deadline_rounding") == 1, date_sub(next_day(col("deadline_date"), day_of_week), 7)).otherwise(
    col("deadline_date")))
```

Comment: I am still getting an Error: ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.

Comment: The issue seems to be passing the deadline_rounding to the function next_date.    "if column == -1:"